# Optimizing recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have incoming tree-like data and I need to transform it into something slightly different.
I created a class method:

```
normalizeMyStuff(data) {
  return data.map(item => {
     //do this..
     //do that..
     const children = item.children ? this.normalizeMyStuff(item.children) : undefined
     return {
       ...some properties,
       children,
     }
  })
}
```

But with huge amount of data, when this method runs, it freezes my browser for a few seconds. This is not the experience I want to provide.
What could I do to optimize it?

Comment: Before anything else, is `async` an option for you?

Comment: Just how big is this data?  How many nodes in your tree, approximately?

Comment: @melancia I'm presuming that "transforming" is CPU bound, therefore async won't do anything

Comment: @Liam good point.

Comment: @Liam: an async queue of work to be performed longside code to stitch the results together can alleviate such situations by regularly freeing the event loop to do other things.  But these days, with worker threads available, I wouldn't bother trying to write that fairly sophisticated code.

Comment: @Scott Sauyet To be exact, it's 12307 items.

Comment: That's all (nested) nodes, or just the root elements?  Because that doesn't sound overlarge at all!

Comment: @Scott Sauyet a single root element and lots of children

Comment: Ok, but are there 12K nodes altogether, or do those have many more children, and those  each have more of their own, etc.  Because for this to take many seconds to run on only 12K elements would imply that `do this` and `do that` are very expensive.  Is that the case?

Comment: @melancia reworking it into async function is the first thing I tried, but unfortunatelly it didn't help

Comment: @Scott Sauyet There can be a deep level of nesting of every item. So, children are not flat. I would say, generally, there is not more than 30 children in each parent.

Comment: Although that still doesn't tell how many total nodes you have, I would suggest that your best bet would be the answer from CertainPerformance.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to start a separate [worker thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) when the response comes in: send the payload to the worker, do the heavy computational-intensive transformation there, then have the worker send the result back to the main page.

Workers operate in a different environment than their original page, so even if the worker runs an extremely expensive process (like `while(true);`), the original page will remain pretty responsive; scrolling and button clicks will still be possible while the worker is running.